# Ajax Request sometimes causes `XHR failed loading: POST` error

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to run a simple Ajax Request to pass a JSON object from my Javascript file to my Python file in Django. However half the time, I get the error `XHR failed loading: POST` when I run it as follows:

```
var csrf = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/fridge",
    data: {
        "fridgeitems": JSON.stringify(fridge),
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf
    },
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000,
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.fridge);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
        alert('Request could not complete' + status);
    });
})

// rest of code
```

In my python file:

```
fridgeitems = request.POST['fridgeitems']

# do something with the data

response_data = json.dumps(fridgeitems)
return JsonResponse({"fridge": fridgeitems}})
```

I think what is happening is that when the Ajax request is placed the rest of the code runs, finishes and quits the function before ajax call has time to load. I have tried including `timeout` in my Ajax call however this appears to do nothing. How can I make the function wait for the Ajax call to finish?

Comment: Add error handlers and inspect arguments. Check server error logs. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network. Up to you to do basic debugging....we can only guess

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that your request is timing out after a while of not getting response from the server. One likely cause is due to a slow network.

To handle this, do either or both of two things:

**1**. Handle the case where an request doesn't complete with the `fail()` method of the `jqXHR` object.

**2**. Include a `timeout` in the ajax request settings.

I illustrate using the combined strategy below:

```
var csrf = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/fridge",
    data: {
        "fridgeitems": JSON.stringify(fridge),
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 5000 // 5000ms
}).done(function(data) {
    // is called if request is successful
    console.log(data.fridge);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
    // is called if request fails or timeout is reached
    alert('Request could not complete: ' + status);
});
```

Notice, the use of the jQuery deferred objects methods: `done()` and `fail()` instead of `sucess()` and `error()`. The later is deprecated.

Comment: I have edited my code to use `done` and `fail` but I still get the error at times. However even when it fails the `fail` function doesn't run. Why is this?

Comment: Neither does the rest of my javascript code in that function

Comment: What does your `fail` method report as the `status` message? You can put it console log - `console.log(status)`

Comment: The fail method doesn't run

Comment: if the fail isn't working it means you may be getting an empty response. For the Server side I guess you are using Django. See this post for a proper guide: (stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/…)

Comment: I think my problem is that the Ajax request doesn't have enough time to load before the rest of the code runs and quits the function however I don't think timeout is making a difference